# Why does my garage still have power when the house main is shut off?

Tags: electrical, garage

[image]I still have power in my garage.. I cant figure out why I still have power  on. It's a new garage built on to the house.

Comment: Does the garage have a sub-panel for its electric?

Comment: Feeder off a remote panel? We can't say without more information.

Comment: I looked all over.. in my attic climbed in the rafters of the garage nothing but I follow the wiring to the house.. Its not making any sense

Comment: Have you looked at the breakers in the main panel? If you have an old split bus panel (like mine), there is a "main" breaker (double pole) for all the 120 V circuits in the house which may be tripped, but there may be a separate breaker for the garage. Do you have 240 V circuits in the house, say for electric range, electric dryer? Are these appliances working?

Comment: To Jim's point - how old is you main breaker panel?  Older panels have different ways of doing things.

Comment: Where is this property located, what country?

Comment: Shoot  us a photo of everything on the property that looks like a breaker panel, meter pan or other electrical distribution equipment, with any openable doors opened.  The meter pan may be out on a pole somewhere near the edge of the property. Do not use tools to open doors (i.e. don't break meter seals or unscrew the panel front covers, but do unlock padlocked doors).

Comment: It's currently pouring outside so I'll take a picture of the meter later they recently updated it to a digital meter.. I'm in Michigan

Comment: Look at your electric bill    Are 2 meters being used on your property?

Comment: Is this a single-family unit or multi?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like your true main disconnect is at the meter location. My farm has this same setup, I have a 200 amp breaker that feeds the house panel, I have a 125 amp breaker that feeds my shop panel and a 3rd that used to feed a mobile home that was here for a few years. To turn the power off to my shop I have to open the panel below my power meter to access the breakers. Some have the breakers on a side access door but this is where you should find your disconnect since turning off your main did not kill the power. Unless of course you have a second meter but that would show up on your power bill as a 2nd service.